# Not enough input arguments in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to run an analysis in Matlab using a python-coded program. However whenever I try and run the code I get a `Not enough input arguments` error. I've googled trying to figure out where in the code I need to match the input with the output but I am unsure (I'm an amateur at at Matlab btw). Would any anybody be able to see or tell where the problem is? Thank you!

```matlab
function fooof_results = fooof(freqs, power_spectrum, f_range, settings, return_model)
settings = struct(...
        'peak_width_limits', [0.5, 49], ...
        'max_n_peaks', Inf, ...
        'min_peak_height', 0.0, ...
        'peak_threshold', 2.0, ...
        'aperiodic_mode', 'fixed', ...
        'verbose', true);
    
    % Check settings - get defaults for those not provided
    settings = fooof_check_settings(settings);
    
    % Convert inputs
    freqs = py.numpy.array(freqs);
    power_spectrum = py.numpy.array(power_spectrum);
    f_range = py.list(f_range);

    % Initialize FOOOF object
    fm = py.fooof.FOOOF(settings);

    % Run FOOOF fit
    fm.fit(freqs, power_spectrum, f_range)

    % Extract outputs
    fooof_results = fm.get_results();
    fooof_results = fooof_unpack_results(fooof_results);
    
    % Re-calculating r-squared
    %   r_squared doesn't seem to get computed properly (in NaN).
    %   It is unclear why this happens, other than the error can be traced
    %   back to the internal call to `np.cov`, and fails when this function
    %   gets two arrays as input.
    %   Therefore, we can simply recalculate r-squared
    coefs = corrcoef(double(py.array.array('d', fm.power_spectrum)), ...
                     double(py.array.array('d', fm.fooofed_spectrum_)));
    fooof_results.r_squared = coefs(2);

    % Also return the actual model fit, if requested
    %   This will default to not return model, if variable not set
    if exist('return_model', 'var') && return_model

        % Get the model, and add outputs to fooof_results
        model_out = fooof_get_model(fm);
        for field = fieldnames(model_out)'
            fooof_results.(field{1}) = model_out.(field{1});
        end

    end

end
```

I want to be able to run this code without error.

Comment: How do you call your function? Maybe you’re forgetting to set its input arguments?

Comment: The error suggests that you didn't pass enough arguments for the function to run. Could you add the part of the code where you call the function?